# Why does this Golang app use more memory the longer it runs?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

I made this to monitor a few websites and notify me if one of them goes down. I'm testing it on just two urls. When it starts it uses about 5mb of memory (I checked with `systemctl status monitor`). After 40 minutes, it's using 7.4mb. After 8 hours, it uses over 50mb of memory. Why is it doing this? Is this called a memory leak?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "monitor/utils/slack"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var config struct {
    Frequency int
    Urls      []string
}

type statusType struct {
    values map[string]int
    mux    sync.Mutex
}

var status = statusType{values: make(map[string]int)}

func (s *statusType) set(url string, value int) {
    s.mux.Lock()
    s.values[url] = value
    s.mux.Unlock()
}

func init() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid config: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid config: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    for _, url := range config.Urls {
        status.set(url, 200)
    }
}

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(config.Frequency) * time.Second)
    for _ = range ticker.C {
        for _, url := range config.Urls {
            go check(url)
        }
    }
}

func check(url string) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        res = &http.Response{StatusCode: 500}
    }

    // the memory problem occurs when this condition is never satisfied, so I didn't post the slack package.
    if res.StatusCode != status.values[url] {
        status.set(url, res.StatusCode)

        err := slack.Alert(url, res.StatusCode)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

If this belongs in Code Review then I will put it there.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get ` When err is nil, resp always contains a non-nil resp.Body. Caller should close resp.Body when done reading from it. `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a memory leak. One obvious source I can spot is that you're not closing the response bodies from your requests:

```
func check(url string) {
    res, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        res = &http.Response{StatusCode: 500}
    } else {
        defer res.Body.Close()    // You need to close the response body!
    }

    if res.StatusCode != status.values[url] {
        status.set(url, res.StatusCode)

        err := slack.Alert(url, res.StatusCode)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Better still, so that Go can use keepalive, you want to read the full body and close it:

```
defer func() {
    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
}()
```

You can further analyse where memory usage is coming from by profiling your application with [`pprof`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/). There's [a good rundown on the Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) and a web search will turn up many more articles on the topic.

Comment: I think your `defer func() {/*...*/}` needs to be `defer func() {/*...*/}()`. If I don't need the `res.Body`, is there a way to `http.Get` only the `res.StatusCode`?

Comment: Good call, updated my answer. There is no built-in way to issue a GET without retrieving the body; the response body is the primary purpose of a GET request. Just discard it and close it and you will seal that memory leak (though there may be others, so monitoring and profiling would still be advisable).

Comment: I also usually wrap the Body in an `io.LimitedReader` to be safe. If the response is large, it's faster to discard the connection and make a new one.

Comment: @JimB like this? `io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, io.LimitReader(res.Body, 0))` I put `0` since in the example I don't use the `res.Body`.

Comment: @Travis, no, you need to _try_ and read something, otherwise there's no point. If there's a max size you expect, use that, or something small like 1024.